# How deploy a WSP with external .dll

Tags: development, solution-package

I'm here to ask a newbie question...

I'm developing a solution for some web site in Sharepoint 2010. No problem to deploy and test... Then I introduce a new project of a DLL in my Solution... when i push deploy seems all ok, but when i call an instruction that refers to that DLL, IIS resturns a 500 response code...

I suppose it is because the tt2sp.wsp didn't contain the Utils.dll produced by my compiler.

There is a way to tell the compiler to include Utils.dll insed tt2sp.wsp?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you are missing adding the dll to your solution package and that it should be added to the gac.

If this is the issue, you can resolve it by opening the Package node in your solution and then switching to the advanced tab. Here you can define any additional dll that your solution should deploy. This blog post should guide you through the whole process: [link](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/)

Answer (score 6):

In your VS2010 solution double click Package.package

In the bottom of the editor switch to the Advanced tab:
[image]

This will bring you to a screen where you can add external assemblies to the WSP package